# In Spring Data JPA, How to add an Entity during runtime ?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, runtime, entity

In my business, I will to dynamically create model and repository for MySQL.
I have successfully create the java file and complied it. then register the bean for repository and service using beanfactory. 
But I don't have an idea about how to map the Entity. I have searched some similar questions but do not have a clean solution.
can anyone help and show me some code samples ?

Comment: Are you sure that your use-cases requires dynamic adding of new entities (and changing the database schema) at runtime. I would assume that you are trying to build a design that does not match relational databases very well.

Comment: Yes, this is the requirement. I need to support both NoSQL and RDBMS

Answer (score 0):

JPA works mostly with static schema. There are good reasons for this, see discussion on www.java.net/node/666078 .

I know only about 3 solutions:

1) refactor/ change your domain model to be static ( best way but there are some real world situations where you really need at least 1 or 2 dynamic tables)

2) use native queries and  @SqlResultSetMapping for dynamic tables ( this is solution I am using in such special cases)

3) use Jpa provider non portable specific ways ( in fact not JPA) see for example http://www.infoq.com/articles/hibernate-custom-fields

Comment: Thanks for reply. Can (2) support dynamically create table ?

Comment: Yes. For example via em.createNativeQuery("CREATE TABLE SAMPLE_TABLE(SOME_ID BIGINT NOT NULL)").executeUpdate(); And later on using ALTER TABLE ...